# Create mapping to the foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, foreign-key-relationship

Suppose I have this Domain Model:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public String CourseName { get; set; }
    public String CourseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and a relative Persistence Model, optimized for Entity Framework and Code First database creation:

```
public class DepartmentDTO
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CourseDTO> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class CourseDTO
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public String CourseName { get; set; }
    public String CourseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have a test class, where I make all mapping using Automapper:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Department dep = CreateDepartment();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Department, DepartmentDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Course, CourseDTO>()
              .ForMember(dst => dst.CourseId, src => src.UseValue<int>(13)); // in my real scenario this is an autogenerated GUID

        DepartmentDTO depDTO = Mapper.Map<DepartmentDTO>(dep);
    }

    public static Department CreateDepartment()
    {
        ICollection<Course> listOfCourses = new List<Course>();
        listOfCourses.Add(new Course { CourseDescription = "A dummy course", CourseName = "Test Course" });
        return new Department { DepartmentId = 42, DepartmentName = "Test Department", Courses = listOfCourses };
    }
```

So far so good, the map is almost complete, and only one thing is missing: the `CourseDTO.DepartmentId` should be `42`.

In this case everything is fine cause I can access to the value through `dep.DepartmentId`, but this is not the real scenario.

How can I configure AutoMapper to reach my goal?

Comment: Crazy question I'm sure, but why have a separate domain and persistence model? Seems like a lot of work going back and forth.

Comment: It's not so crazy. We want to maintain as clean as possible the domain model. We can ignore the performance issues since we have a bus and a read model for the read operation. Anyway right now is just a test.

Comment: But using AutoMapper couples these models two together, no? So it's not clean any more, there's a hidden connection between the two.

Comment: There's a repository specific for each aggregate (say: RootAggregateRepository) that extends a generic repository. All map creation is make inside the root aggregate repositorie's constructor. While the map between DM and PM is realized inside the Add/Delete/GetById method of the generic repository. So... effectively the connection among the model is really hidden. At this point the real question should be: is really necessary? Right now, we don't know is just a DDD test, and we have a lot of question that probably will be posted here soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom Resolver to set the `DepartmentId` for each `Course` when resolving `Courses`.

```
public class CourseResolver : ValueResolver<Department, ICollection<CourseDTO>>
{
    protected override ICollection<CourseDTO> ResolveCore(Department source)
    {
        var coursesDto = source.Courses
            .Select(c => Mapper.Map<CourseDTO>(c)).ToList();
        coursesDto.ForEach(c => c.DepartmentId = source.DepartmentId);
        return coursesDto;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Department, DepartmentDTO>()
     .ForMember(obj => obj.Courses, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CourseResolver>());
 Mapper.CreateMap<Course, CourseDTO>();
```